# Mass transit consumer dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, masstransit

I have a dotnet core console application and wish to inject a class into a consumer.
I have my receive endpoint setup here with a single consumer.

```
sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(appSettings.QueueUrl, ep => {
    ep.Consumer<AddAchievementConsumer>();
});
```

I then have my consumer class here.

```
public class AddAchievementConsumer : IConsumer<AddAchievementQueueMessage> {

        private readonly IRepository repository;
        private readonly IAchievementFactory achievementFactory;

        public AddAchievementConsumer(IRepository repository, IAchievementFactory achievementFactory) {
            this.repository = repository;
            this.achievementFactory = achievementFactory;
        }

        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<AddAchievementQueueMessage> context) {
            var achievementService = new AchievementManagementService(this.repository, this.achievementFactory);
            achievementService.CreateAchievement(context.Message.Title, context.Message.Description, context.Message.Points);
 
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

    }
```

I want to be able to inject IRepository and IAchievementFactory into the consumer using dependency injection.
Now I'm aware on the endpoint I could go:

```
ep.Consumer(() => new AddAchievementConsumer(repository, achievementFactory));
```

Now that would be fine but I wish to be able to use the depenency injection to inject them on their own without having to do it myself as in the future there will be multiple consumers.

Could anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you [refer to the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/configuration.html#asp-net-core) there are [many examples](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/configuration.html#asp-net-core) of how to configure MassTransit using the .NET Core Generic host, dependency injection, etc.

Comment: Thanks Chris I’ll check this out

Comment: hiya Chris, you don't have anymore examples do you? Haven't been able to get anywhere with what's in the documentation. Nothing around injecting into consumers that I could find. Just trying to inject into a consumer in my console application.

Comment: Yet another [page in the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like

```
e.ConfigureConsumer<YouEventConsumer>(context);
```